# Can Express JS listen to external requests and pass fetched data to React JS front end?

Tags: reactjs, express

I am creating a React JS front end for an application, but in addition to having buttons on the UI, I'm also thinking of an external mobile app which can control the appearance of certain elements on the screen, like the font. For this, I need the web application to listen to external REST requests. But as React JS doesn't listen to such requests, I am creating an Express JS backend to handle REST requests.

However, here is where I am facing the problem that all tutorials of Express JS + React JS explain how to catch requests from the React front end and serve back data to the front end itself. They don't say how to listen to requests from external sources and send something like push notifications to the front end to inform it of the changes. Is this even possible, or should I pursue some different avenue to get this functionality?

Resources referred:
[Resource 1](https://rapidapi.com/blog/create-react-app-express/)
[Resource 2](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-react-frontend-a-node-express-backend-and-connect-them-together-c5798926047c/)

Answer (score 0):

For front end you can use JS **XML xhttp** or **Fetch Api** or **Axios** Library to receive response from server.

example Front End :
fetch api to receive response from server
**example of url : http://localhost:3000**.
**Content-Type** as per as your **data type**
code :

```
fetch("url",{
method : "post",
headers : {
"Content-Type" : "application/json"
},
body : JSON.stringify({name : 'abc'})
}).then(async (res) => console.log(await res.json())).catch((err) => console.log(err)
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps you didn't get my question. As I said, I already am seeing the tutorials where I am setting up an Express JS server and fetching data from it into the front end React JS. I have this code in React JS to fetch the data: axios.get('http://localhost:3000/').then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
} However, I am explicitly querying the backend to fetch the data. The backend itself isn't notifying the front end about any data which has been sent to any of its APIs externally.

Comment: do you want that server automatically notifies the front end that server has  sent data over any API?